# OpenLayers - pan map on pressing mouse wheel

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-2, mouse-wheel

In OpenLayers 2, it was possible to pan the map with either pressing the left button or the mouse wheel (middle button). In later Versions, the mouse wheel options seems to have disappeared.

Is it possible to get this back?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to replace the default DragPan interaction with a custom one which allows both buttons 0 and 1

```
import 'ol/ol.css';
import Map from 'ol/Map';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import View from 'ol/View';
import {DragPan, defaults as defaultInteractions} from 'ol/interaction';

const map = new Map({
  interactions: defaultInteractions({dragPan: false}).extend([
    new DragPan({
      condition: function (mapBrowserEvent) {
        return (
          mapBrowserEvent.originalEvent.isPrimary &&
          mapBrowserEvent.originalEvent.button < 2
        );
      },
    }),
  ]),
  layers: [
    new TileLayer({
      source: new OSM(),
    }),
  ],
  target: 'map',
  view: new View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 2,
  }),
});
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-forked-9y6lz6?file=/main.js